# Is $\pi e$ irrational?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

During our ongoing research, we need to prove that $\pi e<\lceil \pi e\rceil$.
Is $\pi e$ irrational?

How to prove it?

Thanks-
mike

Comment: Is that the ceiling function? If so what does this have to do with irrationality?

Comment: If my memory serves, it is unknown whether $\pi e$ or $\pi + e$ is irrational, but we know that at least one of them is irrational because otherwise $p(x) = (x+\pi)(x+e)$ would have a rational root.

Comment: @Noam I assume it's because the OP wants a strict inequality. The irrationality of $\pi e$ would guarantee this.

Comment: @Noam Maybe the strict inequality is of OP's concern?

Comment: Note:  it is not difficult to estimate the product...getting $\pi\times e\sim 8.539734...$.  This is enough to show that $\pi\times e < \lceil \pi \times e \rceil$, but I don't see any connection between this and irrationality.

Comment: Of course, knowing that $\pi e$ is irrational is sufficient for a strict inequality; it is far from necessary, so it does seem a bit silly to phrase the question this way.

Comment: Yes. I need the strict inequality.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu, I was trying not to use the numerical calculations to show the strict inequality.  If the numerical calculation is acceptable, then it is enough for me. Thanks

Comment: Even with just two significant figures for $\pi$ and $e$, we get $8.37=3.1\cdot 2.7<\pi\cdot e < 3.2\cdot 2.8 = 8.96$ implying the cieling is $9$.